# How to handle multiple user types with Django 1.7 user model

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Python and Django. I am trying to setup user model for different roles like Agents, Brokers, Company and Customer. Each of these roles can register with the site as a user. Then Agents and Brokers can have public facing profile pages.

Do I have to use custom user model or built in user model will work? I have additional properties like license, location, languages, photo etc for Agents and Brokers.

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    AGENTS = 'AG'
    BROKERS = 'BR'
    COMPANY = 'CP'
    CUSTOMER = 'CM'

    ROLE_IN_CHOICES = (
        (AGENTS, 'Agent'),
        (BROKERS, 'Broker'),
        (COMPANY, 'Company'),
        (CUSTOMER, 'Customer'))

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    secondary_phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

......

```
@property
def is_agent(self):
    return self.role in (self.AGENTS)

@property
def is_customer(self):
    return self.role in (self.CUSTOMER)

@property
def is_broker(self):*
    return self.role in (self.BROKER)

@property
def is_company(self):
    return self.role in (self.COMPANY)
```

....

Can I not use base User model and achieve same? Am I on write track?

How do I create public facing pages for these roles (Agents, Brokers)?

This is my first attempt with Python and Django. I am using Django 1.7.7 with Python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

You should extend from the Django User model instead and add the extra fields you need:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as Auth_User

class User(Auth_User):

    # add your extra fields here like roles, etc
    phone = CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    # add your extra functions
    def extra_user_function(self):
         return "This is an extra function"
```

This way you have your own fields and also the Django User fields...

After migrating, if you check the database, you'll have auth_user and your_app_user tables.

Just bare in mind that request.user will only give you the super fields... In order to get the extended class you'll need

```
User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

The latest will only have the extra fields and *its id will be the same as the auth.User* **if you don't add any auth_user by itself**.

**Attention: this is important!**

Otherwise **request.user.id** and **your_app.User.id** don't match, therefore User.objects.get(id=request.user.id) won't work and you'll have to query the db to find the your_app.User.id

```
User.object.get(user_ptr_id = request.user.id)
```

Other things to consider

This will work:

```
# you_app.User objects gets vars from auth.User
user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
first_name = user.first_name
```

But this won't work

```
# auth.User trying to get a function from your_app.User
user =  request.user
user.extra_user_function()
```

So the User model could be something like this:

```
import os
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as Django_User
from django.db.models import CharField, ImageField

class User(Django_User):

    phone = CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    observations = CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = ImageField(upload_to='users', default='default/avatar.jpg')

    class Meta:
        # adding extra permissions (default are: add_user, change_user, delete_user)
        permissions = (
            ("access_user_list", "Can access user list"),
            ("access_user", "Can access user"),
        )
        ordering = ["-is_staff", "first_name"]
```

Instead of creating roles on the user, Django already has groups, so you should use them.

The groups follow the same logic:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group as Auth_Group
from django.db import models

class Group(Auth_Group):

    observations = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_users_in_group(self):
        return self.user_set.filter(is_active=1).order_by('first_name', 'last_name')

    def count_users_in_group(self):
        return self.user_set.count()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
             ("access_group_list", "Can access group list"),
             ("access_group", "Can access group"),
        )
        ordering = ["name"]
```

You can clear / add users to a group:

```
user.groups.clear()
user.groups.add(group)
```

Clear / add permissions to the group:

```
group.permissions.clear()
group.permissions.add(permission)
```

There is also a decorator to check if a user has permissions

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required(("users.change_user","users.access_user",))
def your_view(request):
     ...
```

I've tried many things in the past, but I guess this is the way to go.

If you really need roles, and a user can have more than one role, mayb the best thing would be to create a model Role and add that to the user has a ManyToMany Field

```
roles = ManyToManyField(Role)
```

but you could do that with groups

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What is the difference between extending auth_user vs. AbstractBaseUser? How do I tie different types of users to this new model? Creating different user models is better choice vs. one model for all ?

Comment: check the auth.models.py file. The User Model extends AbstractModel but has a meta field "swappable". For what I read, this allows you to replace the model for one of your own, but I'm not sure. As for tying different types of users, use the "groups" field and follow the same logic. You can extend your "Company" from auth.Group, give it more fields and set permissions...Let me add the groups to the answer...

Comment: why do not use [django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user)?

Comment: "installing a custom User model will break any proxy model extending User. Proxy models must be based on a concrete base class; by defining a custom User model, you remove the ability of Django to reliably identify the base class." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-proxy-models

Comment: I guess you could use AbstractUser without problems, but AbstractBaseUser would not work without adding extra bits. In the end, auth.User is exactly the same as AbstractUser.